# TClientDataset CloneCursor not working good

Tags: c++, database, ado, c++builder, tclientdataset

I'm trying to edit multiple records by cloning ClientDataset cursor. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here. Each time I edit another record (inside new Form) all cloned cursors are reset?

I'm using C++ Builder XE2.

https://www.box.com/s/h133nfo63tjjdvkc4ays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Clone dataset and it's datasource should be on the separate (editing) form.